# Stateful dependent Filtering a stream

Tags: java, java-stream

```
indicesArrays.stream().flatMap(n -> n.indices).sorted().filter(x->
//filter x if its difference with its predecessor is less then 5;
)
```

Is there a "natural" way to do this kind of dependent filtering on a stream? How would you do it right?

Thats how I would try:

```
indicesArrays.stream().flatMap(n -> n.indices).sorted().filter(new Predicate<Integer>() {
                Integer lastX = null;

                @Override
                public boolean test(Integer t) {
                    if (lastX == null) {
                        lastX = t;
                        return true;
                    }
                    final boolean include = t - lastX >= 5;
                    lastX = t;
                    return include;
                }
            });
```

But I'm not sure if that's a good approach neither am I sure it would always work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This, in your particular case and for the latest openjdk release at the time (jdk+b132), will work,bbut it's not recommended. Because your `indexArrays` are very likely to be a `Collection<SomeClassWithABoxedIntStreamField>`, whose `stream()` method return a sequential stream, then no interference may be created.

However, if `indexArrays.stream()` returns a parallel stream, you will first have to turn it into a sequential stream with `Stream::sequential`. Working on that stream **may** gives the right result.

Anyway, this kind of code is really not recommended and *may* not be compatible with future Java releases, it break the contract, too.

PS: take a look at `IntStream` and `Stream::flatMapToInt`. They can wipe the cost of boxing and unboxing integer values.